# Error with parsing Rails Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm trying to pass a URL as a param to my Rails app:

```
Started DELETE "/images/0?s3_filepath=https://s3.amazonaws.com/buildinprogresstest/uploads/blllbyq5k3qinl4l/uploads_2F9qggxxf5dvlsor-667601c8f38d8d41af07828accbf3147_2F2014-07-13%252B18.44.29.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-31 11:52:09 -0400
```

The **s3_filepath** is not being properly parsed in the params:

```
 Parameters: {"s3_filepath"=>"https://s3.amazonaws.com/buildinprogresstest/uploads/blllbyq5k3qinl4l/uploads_2F9qggxxf5dvlsor-667601c8f38d8d41af07828accbf3147_2F2014-07-13%2B18.44.29.jpg", "id"=>"0"}
```

If you look closely, the filename includes the sequence "252B18" but the params seems to remove the numbers "52"

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally parameters are url-encoded and decoded on rails side. %25 is decoded to %, that's why it is removed from your input. You need to properly encode this url.

In Ruby you can use CGI.escape

```
CGI.escape "https://s3.amazonaws.com/buildinprogresstest/uploads/blllbyq5k3qinl4l/uploads_2F9qggxxf5dvlsor-667601c8f38d8d41af07828accbf3147_2F2014-07-13%252B18.44.29.jpg"
=> "https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fbuildinprogresstest%2Fuploads%2Fblllbyq5k3qinl4l%2Fuploads_2F9qggxxf5dvlsor-667601c8f38d8d41af07828accbf3147_2F2014-07-13%25252B18.44.29.jpg"
```

If you send this request via javascript you can use escape function in javascript

```
escape("https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fbuildinprogresstest%2Fuploads%2Fblllbyq5k3qinl4l%2Fuploads_2F9qggxxf5dvlsor-667601c8f38d8d41af07828accbf3147_2F2014-07-13%25252B18.44.29.jpg")
```